# Increment numbers for matching text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-processing

In Notepad++, is it possible to find a particular tag in the file and increase the value by 1 for each successive tags, once the value in the first tag is entered? For example:

```
<p id="pg-1">1</p>
<p id="pg-"></p>
<p id="pg-"></p>
```

should look as:

```
<p id="pg-1">1</p>
<p id="pg-2">2</p>
<p id="pg-2">3</p>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "tag"? That's just a number that you showed. I doubt you want to just increment randomly found numbers. Please show exact input and desired output.

Comment: I edited the question, should be ok now

Comment: Are the `<p>`s supposed to be in the same line or did you use formatting incorrectly? For newlines to be respected, either select all and then press Code Sample button in editor or wrap the block with ``` (triple backticks)

Comment: thanks, new to this,, so still learning and have edited it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make an auto-increment thingie in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/1427168/can-i-make-an-auto-increment-thingie-in-notepad)

Comment: Also https://superuser.com/questions/339948/quickly-increment-selected-numbers-in-notepad https://superuser.com/questions/1596134/incremental-number-for-certain-tags-in-xml-notepad

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. We expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem (see all links posted by comment).